# how to draw paths with bezier curves in opencv (python) created with paper.js

Tags: python, bezier, paperjs

I have many paths associated with images, drawn with paper.js application, which produce a json object of format:

```
[[[x,y], [handle1_x, handle1_y], [handle2_x, handle2_y]],  ...].
```

Thus, for each point on a polygon ("path"), I have got x, y and a notion of the handles that control the curvature ("bezier").

How can I turn these paths into contours in python for drawing these paths over an image (to get a mask)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A contour in *OpenCV* is an array of points, `std::vector<cv::Point>`.

So I guess the easiest way would be to output the list of all points of the curve in your json file, (using *Paper.js* `path.getPointAt()` - from 0 to offset to "get all points/pixels" of the curve) and then to create a `std::vector<cv::Point>` in *OpenCV*.

This would create bigger json files though (the list of curve pixels will be bigger than the list of curve points & handles), unless you really have huge amount of data it should not be a problem. If it is a problem, you could also use something like [OpenCV-Beziers](https://github.com/thenatefisher/OpenCV-Beziers) (I have never used it) to compute the list of point in the OpenCV side.

Comment: If it's a lot bigger you can probably use the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to simplify the path. It will smooth out noise if your PaperJS paths are freehand-drawn paths.

Comment: Thanks! the path.getPointAt() from 0 to path.length seems to work great!